# Ошибка при открытии фото

Tags: python, aiogram

Гугли не нашел

```
photo0 = open('ZhanaUrpak2\0.jpg','rb')
```

Ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\77054\Desktop\ZhanaUrpak2\bot_zhana.py", line 25, in <module>
    photo0 = open('ZhanaUrpak2\0.jpg','rb')
ValueError: embedded null characterr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
photo0 = open('ZhanaUrpak2\0.jpg','rb')
```

Символ `\` нужно экранировать:

```
photo0 = open('ZhanaUrpak2\\0.jpg','rb')
                          ^^
```

Либо использовать "сырые строки":

```
photo0 = open(r'ZhanaUrpak2\0.jpg','rb')
              ^
```

Если этого не делать, то сочетание `\0` в строке будет означать "символ с кодом 0", а это недопустимый символ в названии файла.

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ZhanaUrpak2\\0.jpg'

Comment: не работают все способы

Comment: @Zemmeus Способы работают, просто файл находится не по этому относительному пути. Всё зависит от того, находясь в каком каталоге вы запускаете скрипт. И ещё какая у вас ОС, может у вас `/` разделитель, а не бэкслэш\

Comment: Напечатайте ваш текущий каталог, от него нужно путь к картинке строить `import os; print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))`